# D3 - animate stacked bar chart

Tags: d3.js

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/CzkraHLh0xz2kfcDzNOv?p=preview

I'd like to use the legend to animate the bars to show just the block that is selected.

An example of thi can be seen here https://bl.ocks.org/guilhermesimoes/8913c15adf7dd2cab53a

I dont need the stacked and grouped option just the selection from the legend

```
    let legend = d3.select(".legend").append('ul');

    let legendItems = legend.selectAll('li')
        .data(legendKeys)
        .enter()
        .append('li');

    legendItems.append('span')
        .attr('class', 'rect')
        .style('background-color', (d, i) =>{
            return colors[i];
        });

    legendItems.append('span')
        .attr('class', 'label')
        .html((d) => {
            return d
        });
```

Comment: You forgot to link your plunker.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't saved the plunker, should work now

Comment: You have an error generated by the tooltip. Besides that, where is your code to filter the bars? Do you want help with a non-working code, or do you want code from scratch?

Comment: I'd like to learn how to do it. I don't really want code from scratch but a point in the right direction. I take it I need a filter, is that a D3 filter or a naming convention. I have the tooltip working but removed the code to focus on the problem

Comment: add `.on('click', someFilterFunction)` to the `legendItems` object.  Then write that function.  You can filter by using ` data.filter(function(d) { return condition});`. After that, you can update the chart as you see fit.